# Incorrect values for #address-cells and #size-cells in Device Tree

Tags: linux, linux-kernel, embedded-linux, device-tree

I am trying to add a tlv320aic3110 codec to my project and I have been recommended adding these endpoints to the i2s and i2c attributes:

```
&i2s1 {
    ...
    i2s1_port: port {
        i2s1_endpoint: endpoint {
            remote-endpoint = <&tlv320aic3110_tx_endpoint>;
            format = "i2s";
            mclk-fs = <256>;
        };
    };
};

&i2c1 {
    ...
    codec: codec@18 {
        ...
        ports {
            port@0 {
                #address-cells = <1>;
                #size-cells = <0>;
                reg = <0>;
                tlv320aic3110_tx_endpoint: endpoint {
                    remote-endpoint = <&i2s1_endpoint>;
                };
            };
        };
    };
};
```

The problem I'm having is that, when I build this device tree into a dtb file, I get a lot of warnings:

```
arch/arm/boot/dts/stm32mp135-evt0.dts:334.5-15: Warning (reg_format): /soc/i2c@40012000/codec@18/ports/port@0:reg: property has invalid length (4 bytes) (#address-cells == 2, #size-cells == 1)
arch/arm/boot/dts/stm32mp135-evt0.dtb: Warning (pci_device_reg): Failed prerequisite 'reg_format'
arch/arm/boot/dts/stm32mp135-evt0.dtb: Warning (pci_device_bus_num): Failed prerequisite 'reg_format'
arch/arm/boot/dts/stm32mp135-evt0.dtb: Warning (i2c_bus_reg): Failed prerequisite 'reg_format'
arch/arm/boot/dts/stm32mp135-evt0.dtb: Warning (spi_bus_reg): Failed prerequisite 'reg_format'
arch/arm/boot/dts/stm32mp135-evt0.dts:331.11-338.6: Warning (avoid_default_addr_size): /soc/i2c@40012000/codec@18/ports/port@0: Relying on default #address-cells value
arch/arm/boot/dts/stm32mp135-evt0.dts:331.11-338.6: Warning (avoid_default_addr_size): /soc/i2c@40012000/codec@18/ports/port@0: Relying on default #size-cells value
arch/arm/boot/dts/stm32mp135-evt0.dts:332.5-26: Warning (graph_port): /soc/i2c@40012000/codec@18/ports/port@0:#address-cells: graph node '#address-cells' is -1, must be 1
arch/arm/boot/dts/stm32mp135-evt0.dts:333.5-23: Warning (graph_port): /soc/i2c@40012000/codec@18/ports/port@0:#size-cells: graph node '#size-cells' is -1, must be 0
```

The warnings say that the value of `#address-cells` is both `2` and `-1`, and the value of `#size-cells` is both `1` and `-1`. But I have set their value to `1` and `0`, respectively, and it still gives me the warnings. Am I missing something?

I have also tried adding `#address-cells` and `#size-cells` to the endpoint in i2s, but the warning remains.

Setting them to the values mentioned in the warning also did nothing.

I'm very new to device trees, obviously.

Comment: Those two properties are specified in a parent node for its child nodes. So if you declare those properties in a node that has no child nodes, then that's suspicious. IOW a node inherits those two properties, so you need to specify those two properties higher up in the tree for custom/non-default values for that node.

Comment: @sawdust, it's so called **node graph**, the requirements are slightly different to the parent-child form of node subtree.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> But I have set their value to 1 and 0, respectively, and it still gives me the warnings. Am I missing something?

You're trying to assign two special properties for a node in the incorrect node.  The Device Tree Specification (v04-rc1) clearly states that:

> The *#address-cells* and *#size-cells* properties may be used in any device node that has children in the devicetree hierarchy and describes how child device nodes should be addressed.

You're using these two properties in a node that has no children. So that is clearly incorrect.

The parent node is where these properties need to be specified for its child nodes.
The parent of your `port@0` node is the `port` node. So that portion of your DT should instead look like:

```
&i2c1 {
    ...
    codec: codec@18 {
        ...
        ports {
            #address-cells = <1>;
            #size-cells = <0>;
    
            port@0 {
                reg = <0>;
                tlv320aic3110_tx_endpoint: endpoint {
                    remote-endpoint = <&i2s1_endpoint>;
                };
            };
        };
    };
};
```

---

For a very similar example in the mainline kernel, review the `&i2c5` node in **stm32mp15xx-dhcom-pdk2.dtsi**:

```
&i2c5 { /* Header X21 */
        ...

        sgtl5000: codec@a {
                compatible = "fsl,sgtl5000";
                reg = <0x0a>;
                ...

                sgtl5000_port: port {
                        #address-cells = <1>;
                        #size-cells = <0>;

                        sgtl5000_tx_endpoint: endpoint@0 {
                                reg = <0>;
                                ...
                        };

                        sgtl5000_rx_endpoint: endpoint@1 {
                                reg = <1>;
                                ...
                        };
                };

        };

        ...
};
```